# IAM blocks access to AWS CodeCommit repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I set up SSH access to CodeCommit and tested the connection:

```
You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not supported.Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
```

When I attempt to clone or push, I see this error:

```
Access denied: User: arn:aws:iam::##########:user/me@me.com is not authorized to perform: codecommit:GitPull on resource: arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:##########:my-repo
```

Even after adding a policy to my user to access all operations on this repo, I cannot clone or push.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:##########:my-repo"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What gives? Is anyone else having trouble with this?

Comment: Did you also add the policies for IAMUserSSHKeys and IAMReadOnlyAccess? See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-share-repository.html#how-to-share-repository-IAMgroup. PS you should do this for an IAM group, then add the user to that group, rather than adding individual policies to an IAM user.

Comment: Yes, set up a group with those policies and the one in my description.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had a policy that attempted to require MFA login for most things other than setting up MFA in AWS. I ended up adding codecommit as an exemption to the MFA required policy so I didn't have to do anything extra in our developer's environments to handle MFA login for git access to codecommit.

Comment: Needed to exempt `codecommit` and `kms` from our force MFA policy

Answer (score 1):

A few things could cause this:

1. If there are any group permissions denying access to CodeCommit
2. If you are using multi factor authentication, that will not work with SSH (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/temporary-access.html)
3. An IAM policy denying access to KMS

If you post this on the AWS forums, we can use your account ID to help you troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Thanks @zachary, it is likely the second bullet here causing the issue. This is a tough limitation to work around for practical reasons. Do you know whether this is intended behavior or a limitation?

Comment: It is not supported.

Comment: To continue using SSH, you can disable MFA for CodeCommit. Otherwise, you have to use the Credential Helper (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html) over HTTPS. When using MFA with the Credential Helper, you must make sure MFA is working with the AWS CLI first.